# Azure Logics-apps(preview) trigger history

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Greeting for the day
I am using Logicapps(preview) version and I want save my workflow's trigger history in a database table.
So, is there any way to do that?

Comment: The trigger history is maintained by Logic app itself. Any reason you want to store it separately in a table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You can use this Rest API to get a list of workflow trigger histories, and then store them to Table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggerhistories/list

**2.** You can enable `Diagnostic settings`

select `Diagnostic settings` > `Add diagnostic setting`.

[image]

Send the running log of Azure logic app to storage.

[image]

Wait for about twenty minutes, you can get the corresponding log information in the container.

Finally, you can get the corresponding information from the container and save it to the database table.